# How to check if a class implements an interface without navigating through its inheritance tree?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

If I want to know if a class inherits `IDisposable` I have to `Go To Definition` in each of its parent classes and interfaces?

Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Are you referring to navigation within the Object Explorer?

Comment: @Nathan My VS has a Object Browser, but I have never used it before. It is a little faster to navigate through it than the method I cited in the question. It is the same speed as using the Class View.

Comment: Yes, class view is simply an extension of the object explorer (so far as I can tell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an instance of the class in question in a using statement. The compiler will tell you if it is possible with that class or not.

Comment: your solution is the easiest/fastest so far

Answer (score 3):

If you have resharper installed, you can use type hierarchy (Crl + E, H) to view it quickly.

Comment: Very nice, I never knew that.

Comment: In my resharper version it's Ctrl+Alt+H, and still +1

Comment: there are two types of key bindings. I am using Visual studio one.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool implementsIDisposable = (classInstance is IDisposable);
```